# How to solve this optimisation problem when I have varied profits associated with different bags?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem, greedy

Recently I came across an optimization problem. Suppose we have 'n' bags each with varied capacity say 'cj' i.e. capacity of jth bag and 'm' items. There can be multiple instances of these 'm' items say 'qi' i.e. the total quantity of item i. Now a particular item or multiple instances of the same item can be placed in one of the 'n' bags. There is a profit associated with these n bags when an item is placed in it but this profit for an item will be different for each bag say pij i.e. profit of item i in jth bag. Now I have to maximise the profit. 
I know that 0-1 multiple knapsack is NP hard. But I have no clue with this problem. 
Edit 1: Is there a greedy approach to solve this problem.

Comment: This is as hard as 0-1 multiple knapsack, as you can consider the case where the profit of an item for all bags are the same and solve 0-1 knapsack with it.

Comment: @juvian Is there a greedy approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, similar to the one for 1 bag. The complexity would be O(c1*c3*c3... *cn*items amount) so unless you have few bags or small capacities, you would better go for another approach, either approximate or optimization solver